# How do I get the name of an Apple product using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use Python to see if an Apple product is connected to a computer, and if so, get its model name.
When I used `pyusb`, it did not display well.
My code:

```py
import usb.core

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x5ac)
#printing vendor and product ids in decimal and hex
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Our device is not connected')
else:
        print(dev)
```

The result:

```
DEVICE ID 05ac:1203 on Bus 003 Address 005 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x05ac
 idProduct              : 0x1203
 bcdDevice              :    0x1 Device 0.01
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Error Accessing String
 iProduct               :    0x2 Error Accessing String
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 Error Accessing String
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
```

And to me, it looks like the problem is that Windows is reading the iPod as a portable device.
Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you for editing, ''Anonymous''!

Comment: If you are on Linux you can try to use lsusb to see if it can actually detect the manufacterer correctly

Comment: Could the "Error Accessing String" message be caused by the lack of administrative privileges?

Comment: This program is always run with administrative privileges and the platform is Windows.

Comment: Does the device prevent you from accessing it until you enter a passcode?

Comment: I'm using an iPod Classic 4th generation, so I don't have a passcode.
I apologize for the lack of information.